# Как получить значение с таймера и преобразовать его в переменную типа int

Tags: java, android, таймер

Здравствуйте у меня есть таймер, который отсчитывает каждую минуту, мне надо, как-то вывести значение этого таймера и преобразовать его в int.

```
Timer mTimer;
MyTimerTask mTimerTask;

public ServiceTimer() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId) {


    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

    mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask,60000);



    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {


    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное вам подойдёт хранение кол-ва минут в переменной и вывод изменений оной в логи.

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private int minutesCount;

    public void run() {
        minutesCount++;
        Log.d("LOG", "minutesCount: "+minutesCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, сильно помогли)